# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater using np.where

Tags: python, numpy, weather

**Error:**
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater

I am trying to QC some data where wind direction is at 361 (an impossible value) and where the wind speed is above 30. There is one more np.where statement to identify a second wind direction condition. I am checking both the wind direction (where) using an equals comparison and the wind speed using a greater-than comparison (see below). The only line in this program that gets an error is the greater-than comparison for wind speed. I've tried using the list for badLoc (making it a np.array) with the same greater-than comparison and there was no issue, but if I try to change the comparison from equals to greater-than in the WDIR180 variable then I get the same problem. All types are numpy.ndarray. After this, I am using the indexes in badLoc to quality control the data by setting those values to np.nan. Some datas with missing values have already been set to np.nan.

```
wspd = np.array(sortdf["Wind_Speed (m/s)"])
wdir = np.array(sortdf["Wind_Direction (deg)"])
WS30 = np.where(wspd > 30)[0]
WDIR180 = np.where(wdir == 180)[0]
WDIR361 = np.where(wdir == 361)[0]
badLoc = list(set(WS30) & ( set(WDIR361) | set(WDIR180)))
```

I could simply silence the warning, but I was hoping to see if anyone had any idea why it's giving me this particular runtime error?

Comment: Presumably you have a string or something in the file. Checking for equality between a number and a string is perfectly reasonable... asking which is greater does not make sense (python 2 used to give a nonsense lexicographical output based on the name of the types. That's now gone).

Comment: Could you maybe remove all the unnecessary info? The problem seems to boil down to you getting a runtime warning in the line `WS30 = np.where(wspd > 30)[0]` which I found out after reading all of this...

Comment: I read it in as a DataFrame specifying dtype as np.float64 for that column to save memory. I would expect that to fail if there was a stray string. There are no headers. II also used the mask function for any empty strings or strings with a single space earlier so that any missing of QC'd values are np.nan. I was suspecting it could be np.nan or numpy issue? I also do a similar np.where in a script that comes immediately after this, that has NO issues.  Do you think I should just silence? Or is it a big deal that might have an actual impact on the accuracy of the program?